# Random generator using stack data structure

Tags: python, random, stack

```
class Stack:
     def __init__(self):
         self.container = []  

     def isEmpty(self):
         return self.size() == 0   

     def push(self, item):
         self.container.append(item)  

     def peek(self) :
         if self.size()>0 :
             return self.container[-1]
         else :
             return None

     def pop(self):
         return self.container.pop()

     def size(self):
         return len(self.container)

s = Stack()
s.isEmpty()
s.push("Cat")
s.push("Dog")
s.push("Horse")
s.push("Snake")
s.push("Lion")
s.push("Fish")
s.push("Bear")
s.push("Tiger")
```

These are my codes using stack. I am having problems trying to come up with a code that can randomly generate only 3 out of the 8 animals as the output using stack data structure only.

Output Example:

```
Dog
Snake
Tiger
```

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Comment: @Andreas I tried something like this:

import random
for i in range (0, 3):
    print (random.randint(1,8))

but im either getting errors or wrong outputs

Comment: Please include your attempts in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate the indexes all at once, then pop the elements one by one and output those at index positions:

```
import random
sample = random.sample(range(s.size()), 3)
for i in range(s.size()):
    if i in sample:
        print(s.pop())
    else:
        s.pop()
```

EDIT (reply to follow-up question from comments):

To pick one of the three chosen animals, push each of them on a second stack in the first loop. In the second loop, repeat the exactly same process, only with parameters changed (choose 1 out of 3 instead of 3 out of 8):

```
import random
sample = random.sample(range(s.size()), 3)
s2 = Stack()
for i in range(s.size()):
    if i in sample:
        animal = s.pop()
        s2.push(animal)
        print(animal)
    else:
        s.pop()

index = random.randint(0, s2.size() - 1)
for i in range(s2.size()):
    if i == index:
        animal = s2.pop()
        print(animal)
    else:
        s2.pop()
```

Comment: Alright, I've tried your answer but I'm only getting the same 3 outputs each time so it's not random.

Comment: My bad! Edited the answer (added the `else` branch), it should work now.

Comment: I got a new problem. Let's say after randomly generating the 3 animals into the output, I want to generate 1 of the 3 animals again. Is this possible?

Comment: Well, the animal is gone from the original stack once you pop it, so there is no way to retrieve it from there. To make it available for future use, you would need an additional stack to push the chosen animals to. Not sure if this is allowed.

Comment: So how would the codes be modified if for example out of the 8 animals, 3 is chosen (dog, snake, tiger) at random, and then out of the 3 chosen, 1 of them is chosen at random again (snake). This time I've created two stacks.

Comment: Grateful for the ton of help you have provided. Next, right after I've added your codes to mine, it seems to work perfectly. So for example, is it possible that after generating 3 random animals and 1 random animal, my final output is Horse. I would like to have codes that can help update my stack to make sure that Horse is no longer in my stack and I can now output my stack into 7 animals now.

Output example:
    Cat
    Dog
    Snake
    Lion
    Fish
    Bear
    Tiger

Answer (score 0):

You can set a random number as the number of `pop()` operation to be done

```
import random
for i in range(3):
    rand = random.randint(0, s.size()-(3-i)) # maximum number of pop is the length of stack - (3-i)
    for j in range(rand-1): # pop rand-1 times
        s.pop()
    print(s.pop())
```

Comment: This code works at generating 3 out of the 8 animals! However, there would be an error sometimes that looks like this:

ValueError: empty range for randrange() (0,0, 0)

Comment: Edited my answer. To prevent that error, the minimum size at the first iteration is 3, the minimum size for the second iteration is 2, and so on.